# syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a search form in MS Access 2013, each time i insert the search criteria in any of the fields created i get the error message

> "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression "*FROMWHERE (FirstName) like "Godswill""AND"

find below the codes

```
<blink>
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
On Error GoTo errr
Me.qryCandInfo_subform.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT*FROM" & BuildFilter
Me.qryCandInfo_subform.Requery
Exit Sub
errr:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
Private Function BuildFilter() As Variant
Dim varWhere As Variant
Dim tmp As String
tmp = """"
Const conSetDate = "\#dd\/mm\/yyyy\#"
varWhere = Null

If Me.txtEnrNo > "" Then
varWhere = varWhere & "(Enr_No) like " & Me.txtEnrNo & "AND"
End If

If Me.txtFirstName > "" Then
varWhere = varWhere & "(First_Name) like " & tmp & Me.txtFirstName & tmp & "AND"
End If

If Me.txtDateFrom > "" Then
varWhere = varWhere & "((Admisssion_Year)>= " & Format(Me.txtDateFrom, conSetDate) & ") AND"
End If

If Me.txtDateTo > "" Then
varWhere = varWhere & "((Admisssion_Year)<= " & Format(Me.txtDateTo, conSetDate) & ") AND"
End If

If IsNull(varWhere) Then
varWhere = ""
Else
varWhere = "WHERE" & varWhere

If Right(varWhere, 5) = "AND" Then
varWhere = Left(varWhere, Len(varWhere) - 5)
End If
End If
BuildFilter = varWhere
End Function
```

Comment: Looks like you need to add some whitespace to your query string `"SELECT*FROM"` should probably be `"SELECT * FROM , etc."`

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with your code.
To make it easy for you and everybody involved: Add spaces before and after every keyword:

```
"SELECT*FROM" & BuildFilter => "SELECT * FROM " & BuildFilter
& "AND" => & " AND "
varWhere = "WHERE" & varWhere => varWhere = " WHERE " & varWhere
& ") AND" => & ") AND "
```

Additionally you are missing to specfify the table you want to select from...
Furthermore your SQL has a trailing `AND`. Either take care of that or choose the not so perfect approch of appening a `1`: `varWhere = " WHERE " & varWhere & " 1"`. (Your version checks for ending with some 5 characters and compare with `And` - that should NEVER be true...)

Furthermore: SQL-injection... I doubt that pre- and appening `""""` changes anything